# EF core optional relationship not working

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I have the following (unorthodox) setup:

```cs
public class OrderShipment
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    ...

    public string Number { get; set; }

}

public class LogisticsAdministrationLine
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    ...

    public string OrderShipmentNumber { get; set; }

    public OrderShipment OrderShipment { get; set; }

}
```

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<OrderShipment>(e =>
{

    e.HasMany(x => x.LogisticsAdministrationLines)
        .WithOne(x => x.OrderShipment)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.OrderShipmentNumber)
        .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.Number)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
});
```

Since both keys are `string` which is `nullable` this should be an optional relationship that shouldn't really be enforced in the database.

My issue here is that `OrderShipments` are frequently deleted and recreated, but the `LogisticsAdministrationLines` remain. This is why i want an optional relationship.

Unfortunately when now deleting an `Ordershipment` i get the following error:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): 
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_LogisticsAdministrationLines_OrderShipments_OrderShipmentNumber". 
The conflict occurred in database "REDACTED", table "dbo.LogisticsAdministrationLines", column 'OrderShipmentNumber'.
```

How can i properly create an optional relationship between my 2 entities?

Comment: This is not a problem with a relationship, but  you want delete a LogisticsAdministrationLines with a reference to a OrderShipment. What do you  wand do with OrderShipment? Delete it?

Comment: `Ordershipments` should be deleted, `LogisticsAdministrationLines` should remain. LogisticsAdministrationLines won't ever be deleted, but if that would happen `Ordershipment` should also be left untouched.

Comment: Try `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull)` and update the database constraint accordingly.